# How to use a loop to display highest mark and lowest

Tags: python

```
#List of students displayed in a SET (J for Java, C For c# , P for Python)
BernhardtJ, BernhardtC, BernhardtP = [93 , 75 , 83]
AshleyJ, AshleyC, AshleyP = [55 , 84, 69]
ChristiaanJ, ChristiaanC, ChristiaanP = [63 , 74, 89]
StevenJ, StevenC, StevenP = [81 , 74, 64]
NicholasJ, NicholasC, NicholasP = [58 , 46, 74]
PeterJ, PeterC, PeterP = [78 , 41, 57]
MosesJ, MosesC, MosesP  = [63 , 42, 21]

Students = [BernhardtJ, BernhardtC, BernhardtP , AshleyJ, AshleyC, AshleyP, ChristiaanJ, ChristiaanC, ChristiaanP ,StevenJ, StevenC, StevenP ,NicholasJ, NicholasC, NicholasP, PeterJ, PeterC, PeterP, MosesJ, MosesC, MosesP]

print (int(BernhardtJ + BernhardtC + BernhardtP)/3, "Bernhardts Average mark for this semester")

print (int(AshleyJ +AshleyC+ AshleyP)/3, "Ashley Average mark for this semester")

print (int(ChristiaanJ + ChristiaanC + ChristiaanP)/3, "Christiaan Average mark for this semester")
```

I want to display the highest average and lowest from the printed integers.

Comment: Put those values in a list and use `max` and `min`.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

The RIGHT way to do this is to put the data in a dictionary to begin with, NOT into individual variables.

```
scores = {
    'Bernhardt':  [93 , 75 , 83],
    'Ashley':  [55 , 84, 69],
    'Christiaan':  [63 , 74, 89],
    'Steven':  [81 , 74, 64],
    'Nicholas':  [58 , 46, 74],
    'Peter':  [78 , 41, 57],
    'Moses':  [63 , 42, 21]
}

averages = []
for k,v in scores.items():
    print( "Average for", k, "is", sum(v)/3 )
    averages.append( sum(v)/3 )

print("High average is", max(averages) )
print("Low average is", min(averages) )
```

Output:

```
Average for Bernhardt is 83.66666666666667
Average for Ashley is 69.33333333333333
Average for Christiaan is 75.33333333333333
Average for Steven is 73.0
Average for Nicholas is 59.333333333333336
Average for Peter is 58.666666666666664
Average for Moses is 42.0
High average is 83.66666666666667
Low average is 42.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i started coding two days ago and absolutely loving it. Thank you tim!